# Can I just say thank you to those of RPG SE?

Tags: discussion, dnd-5e

This may not stay open for long; but I am unsure how to give thanks where I feel thanks is due.

My question is, since I have been here for 2+ years now and several questions and answers, can I give thanks to those few who stand out and the many others who participate in this website who do not stand out as much?

A few of those who stand out:  KorvinStarmast, NautArch, Miniman, Markovchain, Dale M, Purple Monkey, Nitsua60, and of course SevenSidedDie; have all been integral figures in asking and answering the hard questions and, when necessary, editing mine.

I just want everyone (even those who's names I do not remember) to know how important and helpful this website has been to me and my D&D experience.
Thank you RPG Stack Exchange.

Comment: @airtome this 100 percent belongs as a meta post

Comment: This is giving me the warm fuzzies. I'm glad these people have made such a difference. (Great work, all of you.)

Comment: A pleasure to be of help, and Happy Gaming! 8^D

Comment: Ah. Meta.  That makes sense.  Never knew this section existed!  Thank you :)

Comment: @Airatome 10k without discovering meta!? Inconceivable! Welcome, this is the place where we discuss stuff concerning the site.

Comment: Yea...you may have seen me around. Im kind of a big deal over there :P No..but really, it HAS been 2 years and a few months.... I take part in questions and answers here as often as I can. As often as I think I have something to add lol. I really do appreciate the work and brainstorming and back and forth we all put in to this place. I have ended several a tough discussion with a single Stack link

Comment: I'm a little surprised to be included in this list, so I've been at a loss of words for the last few hours. So I'll just say, thank you for the shout out. Glad to know we're doing something positive. :)

Answer (score 8):

### RPG.SE, [you da real DMG](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/events/kevin-durant-mvp-speech)

I started playing 2 years ago, about the same time I joined this stack, actually. I've found this site to not only settle tough rules questions, but also the softer sides of [gm-techniques](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gm-techniques) [problem-players](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-players). The site, and its members are a dragon's hoard of knowledge, skills and information. But even more than that, the site and people have taught me *how* to think, and if there's anything that I can take home from this site, it's *that* skill.

So, I can say, with confidence, the stack... is working as intended.